# How to halt the maven build if a release build for the same snapshot version is available in the repository?

Tags: maven, jenkins, maven-3, maven-plugin

Is there any plugin available in the community or I need to build one?

Comment: Why do you need that? Cause if a build of a release lets say for 1.0.0 has been done the version in the pom is changed via version control...?

Comment: @khmarbaise ~~You might be re-setting up a multi-branch pipeline which will auto-deploy even already built and deployed tags.~~ Nevermind, i misunderstood that question.

Comment: No problem. If I correctly remember a multi branch pipeline will only be triggered by creating new branches and/or commits on existing branches and not on tags. Furthermore if you deploy a second time a release this should fail anyway cause a release is immutable so you can't redploy an already existing tag etc.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote my own enforcer rule for that purpose because I could not find an "official" plugin or rule.

Answer (score 0):

There's a Maven plugin that allow you to replace -SNAPSHOT versions with the corresponding release version here: https://www.mojohaus.org/versions-maven-plugin/use-releases-mojo.html

While this does not halt the build, it's a good start if you want to add the functionalilty.